# paste to microsoft word using applescript

Tags: ms-word, applescript

I'm trying to make a simple applescript which doesn the following:

Switch to Microsoft Word
type *
press paste (command v)
press return

I came up with this but it won't work... Any ideas why??

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Microsoft Word" to activate
        keycode(42)
        keycode(118)
        keycode(3)
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

your using key code in the wrong manner and your tell blocks are not correct try this

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Microsoft Word"
            key code 42
            key code 118
            key code 3
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

In general your code is easier to write and much more readable if you use text wherever possible rather than keycodes.

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Microsoft Word"
        keystroke "*"
        keystroke "v" using command down
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```